# Best Single-Sign-On practices for large organization

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm currently working on several IT projects for a large organization (100k+ members). I'm thinking on providing some kind of unification and integration of all websites that I'm designing.

So my question is, what are the best practices for such integration?

I'm using mainly two `php`-based engines: WordPress and [Q2A](http://www.question2answer.org/)

What I would like to achieve:

- Provide Single-Sign-On (SSO) for all websites managed by me.
- Exchange information between pages, something like user's top-bar on StackExchange
- Provide a SSO plugin for WordPress (there is a lot of sub-organizations in this organization, most of them have simple WordPress based webpages; I would like to provide them with a plugin that allows loging by the users via unified SSO).

So what are the best practices? Is the SSO mechanism itself powerfull enough to achieve that or should I look for some modification of it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two widely used single sign on protocols:

- [OpenId](http://openid.net/)
- [Oauth](http://oauth.net/)

From a technical perspective the biggest difference is that your site has to pre-register with the Oauth server.   The Oauth provider will give your site a token that it must send when you want  to log in a visitor.   OpenID  requires no previous arranged relationship.

It appears that Oauth is the better choice nowdays.    Facebook has always supported only Oauth login for single sign on.   Google used to support OpenId, but has since implemented Oauth and started to deprecate OpenId.

StackExchange took the approach of writing their own OpenId server or allow you to choose from third party providers.   There is a lot less user confusion if you support only one single sign on provider.   It could be your own, or you could just use Google.